# SSDO as 2D filter

Tags: filtering, global-illumination

I've been looking for a way to get SSDO as a 2D filter in Blender Game Engine. I know that it is possible, but I have no idea how. And I can't find any good resources online. Maybe someone can help me with this and tell me the math behind it or give a ready GLSL filter? I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you mean screenspace ambient occlusion? I'm not sure whether the "D" is a typo or if there's another exciting graphics technique I haven't heard of yet... ;)

Comment: I mean Screen Space Directional Occlusion. It is like screen-space global illumination. A mothod WAY better than SSAO.

Comment: http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~ritschel/Papers/SSDO.pdf

Comment: Although the link has no code samples, it walks through each step in great detail.

Comment: @Jon if you'd be willing to summarize those steps, then in conjunction with the link for further details I think that would make a good answer. )

Comment: @Jon this link may help;)